# JavaScript equivalent for PHP preg_replace

Tags: php, javascript, regex, preg-replace

I've been looking for a js-equivalent for the PHP `preg_replace` function and what I found so far is simply `string.replace`.

However I'm not sure how to convert my regular expression to JavaScript. This is my PHP code:

```
preg_replace("/( )*/", $str, $str);
```

So for example the following:

```
test   test   test test
```

becomes:

```
test-test-test-test
```

Anyone knows how I can do this in JavaScript?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
var text = 'test   test   test test';
var fixed = text.replace(/\s+/g, '-');
```

Comment: don't you need to put quote marks around the regular expression? or am I getting confused?

Comment: No, it's a regex literal. If we enclose it in quotes, JS will treat it like a regular string, which results in an empty match, since we don't have anything like `/\s+/g` in our `text` variable. More information can be found at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: Thanks for the reference :) turns out I was getting confused

Answer (score 5):

javascripts string.replace function also takes a regular expression:

```
"test    test  test    test".replace(/ +/,'-');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5yn4s/

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, you would write it as:

```
result = subject.replace(/ +/g, "-");
```

By the way, are you sure you've posted the right PHP code? It would rather be:

```
$result = preg_replace('/ +/', '-', $str);
```

Comment: In this case it doesn't matter if it is `( )*` or `( *)` because you don't need the content of the capturing group, so you don't need the brackets at all: `result = subject.replace(/ */g, "-");` will do exactly the same.

Comment: I think you should use `+` instead of `*`: you want to match one or more spaces, not zero or more. I haven't tested this, but otherwise it might produce `-t-e-s-t-t-e-s-t-t-e-s-t-t-e-s-t- `

Answer (score 0):

See javascript [replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) function reference.

In your case it is something like

```
var result = str.replace(/\s+/g, '-');
```

But that replaces only one space. Working on it now :)

Comment: Needs a `/g` for global replacement

Comment: And needs to be replaced with `'-'`, not `''`.